# How to make UITextField select all first and then edit programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField`. On first click I want to `select all` the text programatically. So I called `[textField selectAll:nil]` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` delegate method. When I make a next click I want it to become normal editing mode. How to implement this programatically?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm, as of now, it takes two taps, right? One tap to show the popover, then another to deselect?

Comment: Yes it takes two taps. But while selecting all, no need to show pop over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This prevents a popover from appearing, when the user taps on the selected text.**

To allow the first tap to always select all the text, and have the second tap deselect, keep your current code in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method, and extend `UITextField` to override `canPerformAction:withSender:`, to prevent the popover from appearing, like so:

**UITextField Subclass**

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    /* Prevent action popovers from showing up */

    if (action == @selector(paste:)
        || action == @selector(cut:)
        || action == @selector(copy:)
        || action == @selector(select:)
        || action == @selector(selectAll:)
        || action == @selector(delete:)
        || action == @selector(_define:)
        || action == @selector(_promptForReplace:)
        || action == @selector(_share:) )
    {
        //Get the current selection range
        UITextRange *selectedRange = [self selectedTextRange];

        //Range with cursor at the end, and selecting nothing
        UITextRange *newRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:selectedRange.end toPosition:selectedRange.end];

        //Set the new range
        [self setSelectedTextRange:newRange];

        return NO;
    } else {
        //Handle other actions?
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

**UITextFieldDelegate Methods**

```
//Select the text when text field receives focus
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField selectAll:nil];
}

//Hide the keyboard when the keyboard "Done" button is pressed
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return TRUE;
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Its not working. The second tap doesn't deselect the UITextField.

Comment: What iOS version are you on? It worked for me on iOS 9.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a new implementation for deselection. I ran this test inside a project created form scratch on iOS 9, in the Single View template. The text field is in the initial view controller of the storyboard. Let me know if this doesn't work for you!

Comment: Its working. But one thing I found is whenever I click on a text in the middle, the cursor is always taking to the last character (i.e) to the end. I need to long press and move the cursor to the character.

Comment: Do you want to find the caret position from the point where the user tapped? This might be helpful: `caretRectForPosition` method of `UITextInput`. You can provide the position from the last `UITouch`

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you need though. Do you want the text to be deselected on the second tap, and the cursor to be placed where the user tapped? If so, I'm not sure exactly how to approach that at the moment.

Comment: yes I want the text to be deselected on the second tap, and the cursor to be placed where the user tapped.

Comment: Double tap is not working after the second tap. @Sheamus